# Android - Receiving Uri of previous image from Camera

Tags: android, uri, filepath, android-camera-intent

In my Application I am taking pictures through camera and showing it in an ImageView. The problem I am facing is that when I take a picture and close the application using finish()(Through back button press), and then reopen my app, then when i take another picture, the image shown is the previous image.

This is my code :

```
imv_camera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            CarrierDETAILS.from_cameraORgallery = true;
            if (CarrierDETAILS.imageNumber < 5) {
                //curr_ImageView=ar_imvID[CarrierDETAILS.imageNumber];
                cameraORgallery = "camera";

                String fileName = "fkd.jpg";

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);
                values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Image capture by camera");

                imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(
                        MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);

                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_VIDEO_QUALITY, 1);
                startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SellActivity_2.this, "Only 5 Images can be uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

And in OnActivityResult :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            String imageId = convertImageUriToFile(imageUri, CameraActivity);
            try {
                Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, imageId);

                String filePath = getRealPathFromURI(SellActivity_2.this, uri);
                CarrierDETAILS.arl_imagePath.add(filePath);
                System.out.println("path from URI " + filePath);
                CarrierDETAILS.from_cameraORgallery = true;

                /**************  Decode an input stream into a bitmap. *********/
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    bitmap.recycle();
                    bitmap = null;
                }
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri));

                if (bitmap != null) {


                    mBitmap = bitmap;

                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // Error fetching image, try to recover

                /********* Cancel execution of this task. **********/
                e.printStackTrace();
                cancel(true);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here imageId is a global Uri variable(used in both OnClickListener and OnActivityResult). At first i used

```
Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
```

but i am always getting null.
What i want is to get either a Uri object of the image or the filepath of the image just captured.

Any help is very much appreciated;